# How to prevent a background gradient from starting all over?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I do have a simple web site with some articles/cards on it. As the background I use a gradient.

```
body, html {
    height:100%;
    padding:10px 0 0 0;
    margin:0;
    background: #99b8cc;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #c8dae6 33%, #99b8cc 100%);
    font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    height: 1000px;
    max-width: 1000px;
    /*overflow-y: scroll;*/
}
```

It's fine! Upon clicking on a card, it expands, which also increases the overall page height. But then when reaching the "first 100% height", the background gradient starts over again.

[image]

How can I prevent it from starting over again? The gradient should then always use the "new" 100% page height.

jQuery is used on this page, if this helps.

Comment: can you provide your html/js, or even better, create a jsfidle ?

Comment: @Trollwut You will have to assign the gradient again using JS/Jquery each time the button clicked,since page height is changing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `height` is first defined to `100%`, but after, you redefine it with `height: 1000px;`, and that override the first one.

Just remove the `height: 1000px;` to solve that.

Or maybe, you need this rule: `min-height: 1000px;` (instead of `height: 1000px;`) depending on what your are trying to do.

Comment: Rofl, me blind. The second height was there for test purposes, sorry. After also removing `height: 100%;` it now works! Please don't ask me why I've put that in in the first place... thanks!

Comment: Went through the JS. It was there for a bit of code which has been removed anyway.

Answer (score -2):

Try applying `background-size: 800% 800%;`.  You can tweak those values depending on the length of your content.

Comment: This will work, but only 8 times... No really usefull. And, by the way, `background-size` is used to specify the size of a background image.

Comment: `background-size` will indeed work for the linear-gradient.

Comment: Yes, this helps. But the cards are dynamically, so I don't know before how long it will be. Didn't downvote, but also doesn't solve my question. :)